# Does my translation of "I want to bring your art to life." make sense?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

> 私はあなたの版下作品に命を吹き込みたい.

is supposed to mean

> I want to bring your art to life.

I'm just wondering if I'm in the ballpark or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation is right and exact.

But I wonder why the word [版下]{はんした} is used in this sentence.

[版下]{はんした} is a expert word used in the printing industry and means [原稿]{げんこう} (copy) or [下書]{したが}き (draft) in easier words.

So, what I want to say is, I and most Japanese speakers won't use the combined word [版下作品]{はんしたさくひん}.